# For loop using range as float object

Tags: python, for-loop

I would like to access multiple pages through this API. Each page has the same URL except for the market_id. I would like to loop through the pages based on the market_id using the specified range.

```
for marketid in range(1.166871138,1.171064031):
    r = requests.get('https://betfair-data-supplier-prod.herokuapp.com/api/race_results/?market_id={marketid}&nz_tote_event_id=', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
```

When I use this code I get an error saying 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

Comment: Only integers are allowed because of the nature of float type implementation, some numbers are not possible to represent in binary code accurately.

Comment: Why not iterate from `166871138` to `171064031`, and use e.g. `market_id=1.{marketid}`?

Comment: By the way, doing several million requests like that isn't a very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use those float objects as the range for the for loop, you need to convert them into integers and iterate through those.

```
start = 1.166871138
stop = 1.171064031
step = 0.0001

startDecimals = len(str(start).split('.')[1]) # Get number of Decimal Points
endDecimals = len(str(stop).split('.')[1])
stepDecimals = len(str(step).split('.')[1])

maxDecimals = max(startDecimals, endDecimals, stepDecimals) # Which number has the most decimal points

# Go through them as integers
for i in range(int(start * 10**maxDecimals), int(stop * 10 **maxDecimals), int(step * 10**maxDecimals)):
    i =/(10 ** maxDecimals)
    print(i) # You can use this as the iterator value then
```

Answer (score 0):

`range()` only accepts values as `int`, however you can enter your enter you range as a multiplied by 10 to the power of something, so that the result will be `int` then for each round of loop divide `marketid` by the same power of 10.

for instance: `1.166871138*(10**9)=1166871138`

as a result,your code might look like this:

```
for marketid in range(1166871138, 1171064031):
   marketid/=10**9
   r = requests.get('https://betfair-data-supplier-prod.herokuapp.com/api/race_results/? 
   market_id={marketid}&nz_tote_event_id=', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
```